# Check date time php

Tags: php

I need send email 30 days before the date_start.

Example: I have event:

1. name street Event
2. status = 0;
3. date_start = 22.06.2018

I need send email when day will be: 22.05.2018 that is tomorrow.

How I can check this?

```
if(date() <=  strtotime(date(), '-30 days') { //send email }
```

This is not working.

Comment: Use `time()` and `strtotime('-30 days')`. Also mark something on that record so you don't email it multiple times.

Comment: maybe even so that when the record is created (date_start I'm guessing?) set a "send reminder" date at that time - use `mktime` and just add 30 to the day argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `DateTime` and fill with dates whatever you want.

```
$past = (new DateTime())->modify('-30 day'); // Date in the past
$current = new Datetime(); // Current date

if($current <= $past) {
   // sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date_diff function as shown in http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%a' ) {
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}

$targetDate = "2018-06-21";
$today = date('Y-m-d');

if ( dateDifference($targetDate, $today) <= 30) {
    // send mail
}
```